# C++ School Project

Tags: c++

I am doing a project for school about math. For it I am writing a calculator in c++ that does multiplication and division with addition and subtraction. I need help with doing multiplication with both numbers being decimals. My code looks like this:

```
int divisionneeded;
int countuntilten;
countuntilten = 9;
while (b == (int)b)
{
  countuntilten = 9;
  temp = b;
  while(countuntilten > 0){
    b = b + temp;
    countuntilten--;
    cout << b << endl;
  }
  cout << "test" << endl;
  divisionneeded++;
  if(b == (int)b){
    break;
  }
  //checkint is a library function
  checkb = checkint(b);
}
cout << "Test" << endl;
temp = a;
count = b;
while(count>0)
{
  a+=temp;
  count--;
}
cout << a << endl;
while(divisionneeded>0)
{
  countuntilten = 10;
  while(countuntilten > 0){
    countuntilten--;
  }
  cout << "TEst" << endl;
  divisionneeded--;
}
ans = a;
cout << "TESt" << endl;
```

for multiplication when both are decimals. I need help because it appears that the program is getting stuck in the third while loop. Please help.

Comment: Instead of `cout << "TEst" << endl;` try debugging with `cout << "DivisionNeeded = ` << divisionneeded << endl;

Comment: Also, I always initialize my variables.  I don't know where the memory location has been.

Comment: I believe that is the problem divisionneeded is not initialized.

Comment: I go to a project based charter school and I didn't know where else to turn.

Comment: @user1095108: Learning to ask for help with part of a problem is just as important as learning how to work the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`divisionneeded` is never actually initialized in this code and that can lead to all sorts of bad things when you then try to use it, which you then do here:

```
while(divisionneeded>0)
{
  countuntilten = 10;
  while(countuntilten > 0){
    countuntilten--;
  }
  cout << "TEst" << endl;
  divisionneeded--;
}
```

Try to initialize all your variables as a matter of habit. Compiling with `-Wall` or similar might point out this problem with trying to use an uninitialized variable. Let your compiler help you by looking through the warnings that it produces. As it turns out this actually seems to run on my system without crashing because `divisionneeded` has been set by my compiler to be 0 but there's no guarantee that this will happen in general so I think this is likely undefined behaviour.

A few other comments:

If you would like more people to respond you should consider making a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Making the snippet of code you post be able to be directly compiled by the people reading it by just copy-and-pasting it into their editor and compiling it makes it much easier for people to answer your question. I had to spend a few minutes changing things around before I could make this code compile, other people may not go to this effort.

I think it might make more sense if division needed was actually a `bool` type that gets set when required. Once again make sure you initialize it.

I would also suggest using c++ style casts:

```
while (b == (int)b)
```

becomes:

```
while (b == static_cast<int>(b))
```

This makes it a lot more easy to search for later on if you do have some issue with casting or you wish to replace this code with something else.

Comment: Good point.  If the first `while` loop gets skipped, the value of `divisionneeded` is arbitrary.